# Why do I get "Error: handler and runtime must be set when PackageType is Zip" when deploying a Lambda function using Terraform?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have defined a Lambda function with Terraform like this:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "this" {
  filename = "${path.module}/src/existing-files-lambda.zip"
  function_name = "ingest-existing-files-lambda"
  role = aws_iam_role.lambda.arn

  runtime = "python3.9"
  timeout = 900
  environment {
   variables = {
      source_bucket_arn = var.source_bucket_arn  
      destination_bucket_arn = var.destination_bucket_arn  
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "lambda" {
  name = "${var.prefix}-lambda-ingest"
  path = "/service-role/"

  assume_role_policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [{
      Effect    = "Allow"
      Principal = { Service = "lambda.amazonaws.com" }
      Action    = "sts:AssumeRole"
    }]
  })
}
```

My python file is just this:

```
import os


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print('Hello world from Terraform')
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
    }
```

However, I am currently getting an error that:

```
│ Error: handler and runtime must be set when PackageType is Zip
│ 
│   with module.ingest_lambda.aws_lambda_function.this,
│   on ingest_lambda/main.tf line 8, in resource "aws_lambda_function" "this":
│    8: resource "aws_lambda_function" "this" {
```

What do I put as `handler` here?

I already have `runtime` specified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You have defined the Lambda function runtime but you haven't mentioned where the entry point to the function is.**

---

That is what the [`handler`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lambda_function#handler) argument specifies - [it is the method in your function code that processes events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-handler.html).

It should have a format similar to:

```
def handler_name(event, context): 
    ...
    return some_value
```

---

The value of the handler argument is comprised of the below, separated by a dot:

- The name of the file in which the Lambda handler function is located
- The name of the Python handler function.

e.g.
`ingest-existing-files-lambda.lambda_handler` calls the`lambda_handler` function defined in `ingest-existing-files-lambda.py`.

If your Lambda handler method is called `lambda_handler` & is inside `ingest-existing-files-lambda.py`, this should work:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "this" {
  filename = "${path.module}/src/existing-files-lambda.zip"
  function_name = "ingest-existing-files-lambda"
  handler = "ingest-existing-files-lambda.lambda_handler"
  role = aws_iam_role.lambda.arn

  runtime = "python3.9"
  timeout = 900
  environment {
   variables = {
      source_bucket_arn = var.source_bucket_arn  
      destination_bucket_arn = var.destination_bucket_arn  
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: how can I check what my Lambda handler is called?

Comment: If you haven't changed anything by default, look for `lambda_handler` in the code - do you have one?

Comment: filename + as in the  python code file name or the function name?

Comment: @Jbd Updated the answer - the default is `lambda_function.lambda_handler` if you've used a template

Answer (score 1):

I think that you need to add a handler here:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "this" {
  filename = "${path.module}/src/existing-files-lambda.zip"
  function_name = "ingest-existing-files-lambda"
  handler = "ingest-existing-files-lambda.lambda_handler"
  role = aws_iam_role.lambda.arn

  runtime = "python3.9"
  timeout = 900
  environment {
   variables = {
      source_bucket_arn = var.source_bucket_arn  
      destination_bucket_arn = var.destination_bucket_arn  
    }
  }
}
```

Check in your AWS console, in the lambda service that the handler is correctly set once the statement above executed.